# emulation of std::unique_ptr in C++03

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, c++03

I'm interested in how C++11's `std::unique_ptr` can be emulated in C++03.  My understanding is that @HowardHinnant wrote a nice implementation that could be found at http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/unique_ptr03.html.  Unfortunately, though it seems that *every* site that discusses this topic links to that page, that page (apparently) no longer exists.  (At least, I can't get to it.)  Is there anywhere else that Howard's code can be found?

Comment: This is the code from the author you specified. https://howardhinnant.github.io/unique_ptr03.html

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but howardhinnant.github.io/unique_ptr03.html only seems to describe the C++11 `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: You are right that link seems to be missing the actual implementation. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem!  I also came across that link earlier, and its name "unique_ptr03.html" *is* rather deceptive.

Comment: Sorry about the broken link.  TimeWarner decided it would no longer host a site for me (with relatively short notice).  Fwiw, I was never really pleased with my C++03 emulation of `unique_ptr`.  I could never get it to work perfectly.  I strongly recommend upgrading to C++11.  You get so many things that just work.   I moved my site to github: http://howardhinnant.github.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code appears to have been moved to [this Git repository](https://github.com/SRombauts/unique_ptr).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the websites'heaven: [webarchive.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20140719191141/http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/unique_ptr03.html)